# Pausing and restarting all Python processes

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting

I have a server which runs our backend scripts for our database (ETL processes, etc). However, for two hours a day we dedicate it to sending our e-mails. The e-mails are the top priority, however, sometimes they become very memory intensive and all processes on the server crash. Due to this I would want to temporarily pause all of the ETL scripts (written in Python) while the e-mail system is running. Once it has completed, I would then want it to resume those scripts once the e-mail system completes.

Let's say that the e-mail system runs on three crons with the following executables:

```
/usr/bin/php /home/Email/main.php --action=set1
/usr/bin/php /home/Email/main.php --action=set2
/usr/bin/php /home/Email/main.php --action=set3
```

I can wrap these three into a script file. However, in that script I need to pause and start all Python scripts. From searching on stack exchange it seems that I can run the following:

```
kill -TSTP [pid]
/usr/bin/php /home/Email/main.php --action=set1 &
/usr/bin/php /home/Email/main.php --action=set2 &
/usr/bin/php /home/Email/main.php --action=set3 &
wait
kill -CONT [pid]
```

where pid is the process ids of my Python scripts (there are multiple scripts). My question is, how can I adjust this to retrieve the pid's of all running Python scripts and loop through them in this? Note: this is being run on Ubuntu 14.04.2. Any other suggestions would also be appreciated. Thanks.

**Solution**

The solution on my system was the following:

```
pkill -STOP python
/usr/bin/php /home/Email/main.php --action=set1
/usr/bin/php /home/Email/main.php --action=set2
/usr/bin/php /home/Email/main.php --action=set3
pkill -CONT python
```

Comment: Look into `renice` to lower the priority of the etl jobs temporarily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find out pids of processes You can use [`pgrep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep)

In Your case could use `pkill`.

```
pkill -TSTP Email 
pkill -CONT Email
```

allthough probably better matching of process name would be wise

Comment: I've tried running pkill -TSTP python to pause all of the python processes, but they still seem to be running (they're still constantly writing to log files). Is there someway to debug this?

Comment: Could you try with SIGSTOP?  I don't know the specific case, but Python is slow on handling signals (see SIGINT with Control-C in python).  STOP cannot be intercepted by python.

Comment: The solution for me was to use "pkill -STOP python" and "pkill -CONT python"

Answer (score 2):

Check `killall` or `pkill` (`pgrep`).

But I think the best way for our case: setup a simple send-only MTA which queue messages, and set it as high priority (with `nice`), so that your PHP code doesn't interrupt, and the sending (*slow* connection creating on network, slow initial connection with MTA on the other side [anti-spam feature]) can go in parallel, without slowing down the rest.